# Raspberry pi not visible in windows 10 network

Tags: raspbian, networking, windows

I have a rpi2 model b. It has ssh enabled and I can use remote access and putty to input commands and make edits.

I can ping both ways (computer to rpi and rpi to computer).

I can see it on my router page [image: router page]

but not in my windows 10 network page

[image: network page]

Comment: SMB (not SAMBA) has at least three versions of the protocol .. .1.0, 2.0 and, surprisingly 3.0 ... now, in windows 10 you can disable 1.0 (because it's insecure, but you can enable it) ... but, does your samba version support 2.0/3.0? and have you enabled it (not sure if you have to specifically enable it or not though, read the documentation :p)

Comment: Do you know which version of SAMBA you are running?

Comment: @JaromandaX I used the line: sudo apt-get install samba to install it. I was just following a guide.